# understanding Delphi notification

Tags: forms, delphi, notify

today I'm trying to understand notifications.
I've a main form like this:

[image: Application main form]

In the form, as you can see, There is a LMDFormDisplay component that I use for mbed forms.
When the user click on the icon situated on the top left of the form I show a second form called frmList.
Here is the code of the main form:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, LMDControl, LMDCustomControl, LMDCustomPanel,
  LMDCustomBevelPanel, LMDFormDisplay, dxGDIPlusClasses, cySkinButton;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    LMDFormDisplay: TLMDFormDisplay;
    pnlCmd: TPanel;
    btnShowListForm: TcySkinButton;
    procedure btnShowListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses list;

procedure TfrmMain.btnShowListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LMDFormDisplay.Form := frmList;
  frmMain.Caption := 'Form embed - ' + frmList.Caption;
end;

end.
```

The List form looks like this:

[image: List form]

This is the code of the list form:

```
unit list;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmList = class(TForm)
    btnCloseListForm: TButton;
    txtListForm: TStaticText;
    btnShowDetailForm: TButton;
    procedure btnCloseListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmList: TfrmList;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmList.btnCloseListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Close;
end;

end.
```

Finally I've a third form called frmDetail the looks like this:

[image: Detail form]
And here there is it's code:

```
unit detail;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmDetail = class(TForm)
    txtDetail: TStaticText;
    btnCloseDetailForm: TButton;
    procedure btnCloseDetailFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmDetail: TfrmDetail;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmDetail.btnCloseDetailFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Close;
end;

end.
```

I would like to show the Detail form by clicking the "show detail form" button that is in the list form. I don't want to add the detail form unit in the list form code, but to send a notification to the main form saying something like: "Hey the list form has notified to open the detail form".
I kknow I can use messages, but, if possible, I don't want to use them but some kind of notification.
The problem is that I don't know how to use them. Can, please, someone hel me?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking - do you mean a TNotifyEvent (basically an event handler you can assign to a button) or do you mean something else? Do you have an example in another language that does what you want?

Comment: The problem is that the new forms must be created. How does the list form know what to create? ISTM that the child form unit should be inlcuded/used by the ist form unit. Of course, there could be some kind of notication center which receives and dispatches notifications, but the forms should all know about it and register themselves with it as receiver. But that is just another form of a message system.

Comment: Looking at how the other form is 'created' it appears that he is relying on the auto-creation and global form variables in the .dpr

Comment: What is "a notification" in your mind?

Answer (score 0):

Well the code for my comment would look something like this:

```
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    LMDFormDisplay: TLMDFormDisplay;
    pnlCmd: TPanel;
    btnShowListForm: TcySkinButton;
    procedure btnShowListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure ShowDetailForm(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnShowListFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LMDFormDisplay.Form := frmList;
  frmList.btnShowDetailForm.OnClick := ShowDetailForm;
  frmMain.Caption := 'Form embed - ' + frmList.Caption;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ShowDetailForm(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LMDFormDisplay.Form := frmDetail; // or other 'show' code
end;
```

Note: I wouldn't necessarily do this in a real-world application, but it should work for the purposes of learning how to assign events at run-time and would allow you to have a ListForm that does not know about the Detail Form.

You could even go further and have a procedure that takes an array of TNotifyEvents and Captions and make buttons on the ListForm at run-time rather than using the form designer.

Comment: My intension is to decouple as much as possible the forms, so the list form and detail form may be subsitute by others forms

Comment: Well that way would work - ListForm no longer needs to have DetailForm in the uses clause with this code. The more common way of decoupling is by use of interfaces. If you're going down that path then you may want to do some reading up on dependency injection (there's plenty of non-Delphi specific stuff available on the internet)